# Can I add a contextual gmail gadget to gmail user account

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have a contextual gadget developed and published in Google App marketplace.
Can I add this contextual gadget to any gmail user account ?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

NO, only Google Apps accounts via a Google Apps marketplace install.